# blog/posts.category.get_absolute_url, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

I am stuck at url problem. I suppose it is because of my 'blog.urls', or the href is my 'models.py'.But I am not sure how to change it. I am a programmer beginner. Sorry for the question if it is too simple.

The issue is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/posts.category.get_absolute_url
Using the URLconf defined in djangotest.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
blog/ [name='list_of_post']
blog/ <slug:slug>/ [name='post_detail']
blog/ category/<slug:slug>/ [name='list_of_post_by_category']
The current path, blog/posts.category.get_absolute_url, didn't match any of these.
```

blog/urls:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    app_name = 'blog'
    urlpatterns =[
        path('',views.list_of_post,name='list_of_post'),
        path('<slug:slug>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
        path('category/<slug:slug>/',views.list_of_post_by_category,name='list_of_post_by_category')

]
```

list_of_post.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/post/base.html' %}

{% block title %}List of blog post{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
     {% for posts in post %}
         <h2><a href="{{posts.get_absolute_url}}">{{ posts.title }}</a></h2>
         <p>Written by {{ posts.author }} on {{ posts.published}} in <a href="posts.category.get_absolute_url">{{posts.category}}</a></p>
         <hr>
         {{ posts.content | truncatewords:40 | linebreaks}}
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

model.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:list_of_post_by_category',args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `posts.category.get_absolute_url` is a variable, it has to be enclosed inside curly braces:

```
<a href="{{posts.category.get_absolute_url}}">{{posts.category}}</a>
```

Also, `{% for posts in post %}` looks kind of weird. Are you passing a list of posts as `post` from the view? I would recommend it to be `posts`, and the condition will then change to `{% for post in posts %}`

Comment: In my view.py, post is the variable. If I defined it as posts, then it is {% for post in posts %}

Comment: @Sue-MayXu That's right.. and `{% for post in posts %}` makes more sense to the reader than `{% for posts in post %}`